# How to get value in for area?

Tags: javascript

i want to make a www like this!

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script language ="JavaScript">
     function random_number()
    { 
  var i;
  var show_text = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
  for(i=0;i<8;i +=1){
  a =Math.floor((Math.random()*39)+1);
  show_text[i].value=a;}
  
  var j;
  var edit_text = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
  for(j=0;j<8;j +=1){
  edit_text[j].value=b;}
  

  
  var count=0;
  if(show_text[i].value==edit_text[j].value){
  count +=1;
  document.getElementById("cc").value=count;}
  else if(edit_text[j].value==null){document.getElementById("cc").value="Please enter numbers first";}
    } 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Random Number </h1>
<p>
Type:
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<br>
Scol:
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<br>
<input type="button" value="Random" onClick="random_number()" />
<p id="cc" /p>
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

i want to people first type the numbers in the upper textbox , then click the button.And show the random number in the below textbox and count how many numbers is matched between the upper textbox and the below textbox.
I have no idea what's wrong with the code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: variable "b" is not defined..for beggining. Also I believe you were planing to put that "if elseif" in a "for" loop

Comment: Protip -> Use dev tools in your favorite browser. Chrome/Internet explorer default button is F12.  That way you'll notice that variable "b" is not defined - plus all other script errors at the exact line they occur.

Comment: Man I'm too soft, need to stop answering questions like this

Comment: The jsfiddle example fixes the error http://jsfiddle.net/croh7suw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **several problems in your function**, I fixed it for you but you need to keep in mind several things to understand why it wasn't working. I decided to fix it because I could afford to dedicate the time to this. But I suggest you look at the developer tools (the console, right here in your browser) to point you in the right direction next time.

- You don't set the content of an element by calling `document.getElementById("cc").value`, this applies to form fields, not a paragraph like in your case
- The syntax for your paragraph was `<p id="cc" /p></p>` instead of `<p id="cc"></p>`
- `b` was never defined, yet you were using it
- Your `for loops` where going from 0 to 8 meaning it will try to access the 8th element in the array (index 7) regardless of the html only having 7 (index 6)

```js
function random_number() {
  var show_text = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    show_text[i].value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 39) + 1);
  }

  var edit_text = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
  var count = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    if (show_text[j].value == edit_text[j].value) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("cc").innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<h1>Random Number </h1>
<p>
  Type:
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="edit" size="3" />
  <br>Scol:
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <input type="text" Class="data" size="3" />
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Random" onClick="random_number()" />
  <p id="cc">
  </p>
```

**Note** that I intentionally removed the part where you show a message instead of the number in case its zero. I believe your question is better answered like this, you can add all the extra functionality that you want afterwards.

Comment: Thank you guys! I have learned your all of the suggestion! I will be more carefull next time! I have made some stupid mistakes this time, but i promise i will not be such stupid to make the same mistakes next time! Really thank you!!!

Comment: It is hard to choose which is the best answer, because you two are the best for me !!

Answer (score 1):

darn it... i just got done fixing it too :/

- `'i'` should of been `'< 7'`, not `'8'`-> this is where it screwed up first because you were trying to access to many
- you are supposed to use .innerHTML instead of .value to set `<p>` elements
- you also messed up the `<p></p>` tag in the `<body>`
- Also your `"count"` verification could of never worked because you didn't put it into a `'for'` loop
- value `'b'` wasn't defined

as stated earlier in the comments - use the browser dev tools (F12 default) and debug. use `"alert('test');"` at various points to see where the script hangs if the dev tool can't help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script language ="JavaScript">
     function random_number()
    { 
     var i;
     var show_text = document.getElementsByClassName('data');


     for(i=0;i<7;i +=1){
        a = Math.floor((Math.random()*39)+1);
        show_text[i].value = a;
     }

     var j;
     var edit_text = document.getElementsByClassName('edit');
     for(j=0;j<7;j +=1){
        b = "lol";
        edit_text[j].value=b;
     }



     var count=0;
     for(i=0;i<7;i +=1){
        if(show_text[i].value==edit_text[i].value){
           count +=1;
           document.getElementById("cc").value=count;
        }
        else if(edit_text[i].value==null){
           document.getElementById("cc").innerHTML="Please enter numbers first";
           return;
        }
     }

     document.getElementById("cc").innerHTML="We have "+count+" matches!";

    } 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Random Number </h1>
<p>
Type:
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="edit" size="3" />
<br>
Scol:
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<input type="text"  Class="data" size="3" />
<br>
<input type="button" value="Random" onClick="random_number()" />
<p id="cc"></p> 
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Glad to see I didn't miss anything :P

Comment: Juan and Matt - you guys are very nice.  A more appropriate answer might have pointed him towards 101 javascript DOM lessons.

Comment: Thank you guys! I have learned your all of the suggestion! I will be more carefull next time! I have made some stupid mistakes this time, but i promise i will not be such stupid to make the same mistakes next time! Really thank you!!!